# Cut or paste in contenteditable element: Get length of affected text from input event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, contenteditable

On `input` events in a `contenteditable` element, a function handles repositioning the caret/cursor and some markup contained in this element.

When I write or remove single characters, `event.inputType.includes('delete')` tells me whether a character was deleted or inserted. In these cases, I simply increment or decrement the caret/cursor position and some indexes in my reactive markup (I use Vue) by 1.

I also want to support pasting and cutting text. Is there a way to get the length of pasted/cut text from an `input` event other than doing a manual comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like it, but here's my solution for now:

1) I store the current length of the text in a variable. In my case that's easy as I only need to support recent versions of Chrome, which support a `beforeinput` event in `contenteditable` elements. This is all I do in the event handler:

```
currentTextLength = document.getElementById('my-contenteditable').textContent.length;
```

2) And this is an excerpt from the event handler for the `input` event:

```
// Get range based on character indexes
let container = document.getElementById('text-with-highlights');

// When adjusting highlight indexes, indexes must
// be incremented in case of insertion, but 
// decremented in case of deletion
let cursorDirection = container.textContent.length - currentTextLength;
```